# N+1 Queries with dynamic search and eager loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have 2 models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :friends, through: :friendships
 has_many :friendships, dependent: :destroy
end
```

and

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User'

end
```

What I would like to do is use a `.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{name}%")` and search through users friends and friend-friends.

So far I have something like this:

```
second_level =[]
first_level =  user.friends.includes(:friends).where("name LIKE ?", "%#{name}%")
first_level.each { |u| second_level += u.friends.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{name}%") }
```

But that creates a problem with N+1 queries, because a new query is made for each of users friends to search in their friends.

Is there a way to do this with eager loading? 
(a valuable article about this was http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/ but it does not address issue for 2 level depth)

In a similar fashion I have a PORO which collects users friends and friend-friends which works fine. The problem seems to be the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my particular situation I wanted a user to only be able to search people by name in his social circle.

That's why I tried turning the whole problem around by first finding ALL users that match the name and then comparing with the array that I get by requesting full network of the user WITHOUT name criteria (that was the method, I mentioned in my description, which did not cause any N+1 queries)

In the end my search method looks something like this:

```
    all_matches = User.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{name}%")
    network = UserNetwork.new(user: user)
    (all_matches & network.full).uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

```
first_level =  user.friends.includes(:friends).where("name LIKE ?", "%#{name}%")
```

After this you could do

```
second_level = User.joins(:friendships).where(friendships: { user_id: first_level.map(&:id) }).where("name LIKE ?", "%#{name}%")
```

Comment: just to be clear- in the first line, the where parameter is filtering out friend-friends, not user.friends, right?

Comment: `first_level.pluck(:id)` 

Map will instantiate the users, pluck just fetches the data.

Comment: @Kkulikovskis the first line is the same as your one.

Comment: @ddgd - I assume he wants to do something with the first level users in the view anyway.

Comment: @japed I wrote another answer of how I solved the problem(maybe you can suggest a better one) The `full` method for `UserNetwork` aggregates user network by doing the same thing as in the description but without `where(...)`